# Body Images won't display in Snake Game using Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

'm developing a Snake Game in C# using Windows Forms, and I've encountered an issue with the body images of the snake not displaying correctly. I have images for different snake body parts, such as "body_topleft.png," "body_topright.png," "body_vertical.png," "body_horizontal.png," "body_bottomleft.png," and "body_bottomright.png."

The head and tail images are displaying correctly, and I've implemented logic to determine the appropriate body image based on the direction of the snake. However, when the snake grows, I'm seeing a blank space in between the head and tail, and the body images are not showing as expected.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
// ...

for (int i = gameList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        // Update the head image based on the direction
        gameList[0].Image = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("head_" + Direction);
        // ... (collision logic)
    }
    else
    {
        string bodyImageKey;

        if (i == gameList.Count - 1) // Tail
        {
            // Determine the tail image based on the direction
            if (Direction == "right") bodyImageKey += "tail_left";
            else if (Direction == "left") bodyImageKey += "tail_right";
            else if (Direction == "up") bodyImageKey += "tail_down";
            else if (Direction == "down") bodyImageKey += "tail_up";
            gameList[i].Image = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(bodyImageKey);
        }
        else
        {
            // Determine the correct body image based on the directions
            string previousDirection = GetDirection(gameList[i - 1], gameList[i]);
            string nextDirection = GetDirection(gameList[i], gameList[i + 1]);
            bodyImageKey = "body_" + previousDirection + nextDirection;
            gameList[i].Image = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(bodyImageKey);
        }

        gameList[i].Location = new Point(gameList[i - 1].Location.X, gameList[i - 1].Location.Y);
        gameList[i].Size = new Size(MainPieceSize, MainPieceSize);
    }
}

// ...
```

Comment: Use the debugger to see the values you are getting for `bodyImageKey`.

Comment: Yes, put a breakpoint where you set `bodyImageKey ` and step through, watching the variables.